# Node - working with webservice with request restrictions

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am consuming a webservice in a node project.

The webservice has restricitions - i can make maximum 10 requests per minute.

I can write functions which make the right requests, get data back etc.

Request #1 - give me Persons (this returns an array of 1000 people)
Request #2 - Give me each persons excercise list for the last week (I have to make a request for 24 hours at a time (7 requests per person) (I need to make 1000 requests, but keep it to a maximum of 10 requests per minute) -

I have attemptet setTimeout, event listeners etc, but no matter what, my code rushes to the end - giving me the right data for the first few people before I am getting "too many requests" back from the server...

Can anybody suggest the correct approach ?

Comment: You could use a generic rate limiter module like [`limiter`](https://github.com/jhurliman/node-rate-limiter).

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please, could you provide some code of your specific problem. That prove how far did you try and it will help other members to understand your problem better, at the time, you will give them a context of your issue. Please, check these links: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask